# I need a sdk apk path when click on apk

Tags: android

When I am click on the apk i need to show the apk path in the toast format.how can handle the events when click on the apk. How to get the path where apk is installed from sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

/data/data/APP_PACKAGE_NAME

but you wont able to read that unless you have a rooted device

Comment: Suppose i have 2 same apks in different folders in sdcard then how can get the path specific installed apk path